# AngularJS complex table design with ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, html-table

I am trying to obtain a table like the one in the image below using HTML5.

[image: Layout of the table that I want to recreate]

In practice the table describes a multi-dimensional matrix. There are Class A and Class B (in yellow). For each of those, there are three modes, highlighted in blue. For each one of the modes of the classes I have different values for the parameters, highlighted in green. The grey cells would report the values for all the combinations.

The size of the modes and parameters are not known a priory (but are the same for class A and class B), so I would like to use ng-repeat to automatically fill the vertical and horizontal headers of the table, opportunely using `colspan` and `rowspan`.

The problem that I am facing is that I cannot successfully write the Class A header and I get stuck trying to use `rowspan` in the modes and the parameters.

I initially tried to use nested tables but the problem is that then the cells in the grey area are not aligned with the headers. Nonetheless, here is the code I used:

```
<table class=" table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <table class=" table-bordered">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="{{getTotalNumCombinations()}}">class B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="{{params.length}}" ng-repeat="m in modes track by $index">{{m}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td ng-repeat="i in getCombinationsArray() track by $index">{{params[getModule($index)]}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table class=" table-bordered">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>class A</td>
              <td>
                <table class=" table-bordered">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="m in modes track by $index">
                      <td>{{m}}</td>
                      <td>
                        <table class="table-bordered">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="p in params track by $index">
                              <td>{{p}}</td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class=" table-bordered">
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="i in getCombinationsArray() track by $index">
              <td ng-repeat="j in getCombinationsArray() track by $index">({{i}},{{j}})</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the JS file I have

```
$scope.params = ['par1', 'par2', 'par3', 'par4', 'par5'];
$scope.modes = ['mode1', 'mode2', 'mode3'];
$scope.getNumCombinations = function() {
  return $scope.params.length * $scope.modes.length;
};

$scope.getCombinationsArray = function() {
  var combinations = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.getNumCombinations(); i++) {
    combinations.push(i)
  }
  return combinations;
};

$scope.getModule = function(index){
  return index % $scope.params.length;
};
```

(I know the getCombinationsArray() is very ugly, but did not know how to solve it elegantly)

Anyway, since the solution above does work well as the grey cells do not align well to the headers, I tried another approach which does not use nested tables:

```
<table class=" table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="{{getNumCombinations()}}">class B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="{{params.length}}" ng-repeat="m in modes track by $index">{{m}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td ng-repeat="i in getCombinationsArray() track by $index">{{params[getModule($index)]}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="{{getNumCombinations()}}">class A </td>
      <td ng-repeat="m in modes">{{m}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, it does not work and this is where I unfortunately got stuck.

I am therefore wondering whether there is another approach that I am not considering.

**EDIT:
Here is the [Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jc9lOm?p=preview) with the two versions**

Comment: What if you ng-repeat your last tr for every grey-cell-row and conditionally show td's on whether it's in a "new" class/mode, would that work?

Comment: Hi @Noppey, I am not sure I understood your suggestion. I added a Plunker link as it may help seeing the code better. Could you please explain in code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with your second method. You are ng-repeating over column for modes, this cannot work. You should ng-repeat over every row

```
<tr>
    <td class="classColor" rowspan="{{getNumCombinations()}}">class A </td>
    <td class="modeColor" ng-repeat="m in modes">{{m}}</td>
</tr>
```

This should change to (pseudo-code)

```
<tr ng-repeat="par in parsInClassA">
    <td ng-show="onlyFirstTime" rowspan="pars.length">
        Class A
    </td>
    <td ng-show="onlyForFirstParInMode" rowspan="lengthOfParsInThisMode()">
        {{ par.mode }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ par }}
    </td>
    <td ng-repeat="par2 in parsInClassB">
        {{ matrixValue(par,par2) }}
    </td>
</tr>
```